FME sharepoint online connector template broken?
At the moment im trying to use the multitenant sharepoint online connector of FME (FME HUB).
This api should connect me with my sharepoint environment. However at the moment im facing difficulty's, see error below.

It seems to me that the template is broken as it worked fine in the beginning. Has anyone faced the same problem or knows a work around or how i can get my template working again.
Much appreciated!
